# Prevent custom Processing Algorithm from returning output on error

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

In my script I make a copy of input layer and perform some actions on it. I can't figure out how to stop QGIS from returning the output layer on error. I've tried returning nothing, but if parameter was defined it gets returned no matter what. `instance.removeParameter()` also has no effect.
Here is a minimal example of my code:

```py
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import (QgsField,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsFeature)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant


@alg(name='somename', label='somelabel',
     group='somegroup', group_label='somegroup')
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name='INPUT', label='In')
@alg.input(type=alg.SINK, name='OUTPUT',
           label='Out')
def skryptTN(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """
    stuff
    """
    source = instance.parameterAsSource(parameters, 'INPUT', context)

    flds = source.fields()

    (sink, dest_id) = instance.parameterAsSink(parameters, 'OUTPUT', context,
                                               flds, source.wkbType(), source.sourceCrs())

    for in_feat in source.getFeatures():

        out_feat = QgsFeature()

        out_feat.setFields(flds)

        for i in source.fields():
            name = i.name()
            out_feat[name] = in_feat[name]

        out_feat.setGeometry(in_feat.geometry())

        if in_feat['field_1']:
            out_feat['field_1'] = 'something'
        else:
            feedback.reportError(f'Error because of reasons!')
            return # this is not stoping output feature sink from being returned

        sink.addFeature(out_feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

    return {'OUTPUT': dest_id}
```

How to stop script from creating and returning output layer ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

```
raise Exception('Error because of reasons!')
```

rather than or in addition to

```
feedback.reportError('')
```

to prevent output layer from being created and returned.

Comment: This shows a rather cryptic traceback to the user, is there a cleaner way?

Comment: yes -> QgsProcessingException

Answer (score 2):

You could use https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsProcessingException.html :

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingException
[...]
raise QgsProcessingException("Your message here")
```